# Moving the Text drawn by TextOut() Function

Tags: winapi, drawing

I'm trying to redraw some text I drew on window at x and y coordinates say (100, 100) to a new location (500, 500). when I redraw the text, it doesn't erase the old text at (100, 100) until I refresh the window (like do a minimize and maximum). how can you update the window to display the current text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx), [UpdateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28VS.85%29.aspx).